# Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory " when submitting doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform

I have recently migrated my site from Google Cloud to AWS EC2 and I'm using node.js.

The site is a job website and when I try to submit a file I now get the below error message.

Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "

The submission works fine on local host ( and also did when it was hosted on GCP). Please can you help me understand why this would be and how to fix it? Here is the code for the CV submission

```
if (req.file){
    console.log("sending CV:"+req.file.path);
  var CVLibrary = {
    url: 'http://www.website.co.uk/cgi-bin/cvsubapi.pl',
    formData:
        {
          title: title,
          firstname: name,
          lastname: lastName,
          email: email,
          county: city,
          town: address2,
          postcode: postCode,
          telephone: phone,
          salary: salary,
          age: Age,
          affiliateID: 20998,
          industry: "Retail",
          affiliatepassword: "coregalm",          
          currentjobtitle: jobCategories ,
          doc: {
            value: fs.createReadStream(req.file.path),
            options: {
              contentType: "application/msword",
              filename: "cv.docx"
            }
          }
        }
  };
  console.log("CV data:" + JSON.stringify(CVLibrary));
  request.post(CVLibrary, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("CV Library request sent with error" + error + " body." + body);
      //res.status(400).send(error);
    } else {
      //res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      //res.send(new Buffer(body));
      console.log("request sent correctly CV Library:" + body);
      //res.send(body)
    }
  });
```

res.render('learnnewskills', {

```
title: 'Welcome to job site', userInfo: {
  title: title,
  name,
  firstname: name,
  lastname: lastName,
  email: email,
  mobile: phone,
  subAffiliate: listId,
  dob: dob_day + '/' + dob_month + '/' + dob_year,
  optindate: currentTimestamp,
  street1: address1,
  address2,
  towncity: city,
  postcode: postCode,

  tickYes,
  tickYes1,
  ipaddress: ipaddress,
  courseInterestYes:"",
  specificCourseInterest:"",
  costAwareYes:"",
  currentJob,
  list: listId,
  currentTimestamp,
  redcoursetickyes:"",
  penaltyPoints:"",
  DrivingBan:"",
  Redlicence:""
}
```

});

});

Comment: The error doesn't mention any part of your shared code, can you share the code where it says res.render(.........)

Comment: sure I just added that part

Comment: But the error says 'index' view. Don't you render somewhere the index view ?

Comment: no that's the weird thing. I'm not rendering or attempting to render Index at all. I'm only trying to render 'learnnewskills', which does render in local host